# Paste doesnt work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, paste, copy-and-paste

Every time I try to paste (ctrl+v or ctrl+shift+v) it doesnt work. This issue only occur in Firefox.
In fact, I do can copy things from Firefox and paste them in other apps. Therefore the issue is only with the paste and only in this app (Firefox).

Comment: What website are you visiting? What kind of HTML input widget is involved? The address bar? A textarea? A normal textfield? A password field? Also, what is your Firefox version? Which flavor of Ubuntu are you using? What is your Ubuntu version? What is the significance of pressing Shift while pasting in Firefox? (I knew about only ctrl+V, in the context of Firefox.)

Comment: Crtl+Shift+c and Ctrl+Shift+v is for console, elsewhere you can use Ctrl+c and Crtl+v without Shift.

Comment: @Levente
I cant even paste on the search top field, also I had tried google main page. Or googlesheets/docs. Also tried at google colab notebooks but cant paste code. I cant even paste text here in the comment(tried copying it from LIbreOffice Writer)
Tried to copy text. 
Firefox 102.0
Ubuntu 2020.04.4 LTS
(As comment below mention, I didnt knew, shift is only for the console)

Question has being closed because realted to another but that question is for ubuntu 21, therefore doesnt resolve my problem.